# RavenDB: What is best practice for dealing with the 128 item limit when saving large amounts of data?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am transferring documents held in a SqlServer database to a RavenDB database. The process is simple but, in line with RavenDB's 'safety first' principle, only the first 128 documents are actually stored.

I understand why this is the case and I also know this limit can be adjusted for the document store as a whole, however, given that storing more than 128 docs in a given operation is not too unusual, I would like to know what the best practice is?

Here is my code to show an example of how I get around the limit. Is there a more elegant way?

```
public static void CopyFromSqlServerToRaven(IDocumentSession db)
{
    var counter = 0;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(SqlGetContentItems, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                counter++;
                db.Store(new ContentItem
                            {
                                Id = reader["Id"].ToString(),
                                Title = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                                Description = reader["ShortDescription"].ToString()
                            });
                if (counter < 128) continue;
                db.SaveChanges();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store how much documents that you want in one operation. No need to save changes in chunks.

Comment: You are correct :-) I was being fooled by my unit-test that was only retrieving 128 items at a time. I switched to using the `RavenQueryStatistics` and checked the `TotalResults` instead and sure enough, all the docs were being saved after all.